# Insert very large chunks of data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bigdata, sql-insert

I have a table in my database that I need to split to two tables. The table has 100,050,000 records. I need a fast way to accomplish this.

I have tried this:

```
    DECLARE @from BIGINT = 0,
        @step BIGINT = 1000000,
        @currentSourceCountBIGINT = 0

SELECT @currentSourceCount = COUNT_BIG(1) FROM dbo.SourceTable

WHILE @from < @currentSourceCount
BEGIN       
    INSERT INTO dbo.DestinationTable WITH (TABLOCKX)(col1, col2, col3, col4)
    SELECT t1.col1,
            t1.col2,
            t1.col3,
            t1.col4
    FROM (SELECT a.col1,
                    a.col2,
                    a.col3,
                    a.col4
            FROM (  SELECT st.col1,
                        st.col2,
                        st.col3,
                        st.col4,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY st.Id) AS RowNumber
                FROM dbo.SourceTable st) a
    ) AS t1
    WHERE t1.RowNumber BETWEEN @from AND @from + @step

    SET @from += @step + 1
END
```

But even this solution is too slow. I filled in the foreign keys of the tables, only the primary key remained, which is set as IDENTITY.

In each pass of the loop, I insert different data into two new tables. With this number of records, it made about 1/3 of the records in about 4 hours of running time. Is there any way to make the process even faster?

Comment: Do you have any kind of `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` column on your table `dbo.SourceTable `? What is `au.Id`? The only object referenced in that scope is aliased as `st`.

Comment: All foreign keys are disabled in the target table (indexes, foreign keys) except the primary key (IDENTITY). I'll fix it - that was a typo

Comment: I'm asking about the primary key in `dbo.SourceTable` not `dbo.DestinationTable`. If it does have one, is it `CLUSTERED`? How is the primary key generated? Is it an `IDENTITY`/`SEQUENCE`? Are there large gaps or not?

Comment: primary key is like IDENTITY. there are no big gaps. The data is not deleted from the tables, i.e. the IDs are consecutive

Comment: `CLUSTERED`/`NONCLUSTERED`? If the latter, do you have a `CLUSTERED INDEX`? What do you mean by it's "like" an `IDENTITY`?

Comment: yes, clustered index...  CREATE TABLE Dest/Source (Id AS PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY)

Comment: You would likely be better off iterating on the ID then, not a `ROW_NUMBER` on the id. Something like this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Dpeimulo) (not posted as an answer, as I'm not in a position to test).

Comment: I thought about this solution. However, I only have test data, which may not match the reality of the production database - that's why ROWID() is used there

Comment: Then you should be finding out about the data you *will* be working with.

Comment: I suggest you to have a look into Erik Darling's blog: [Copying Large Tables Efficiently In SQL Server](https://erikdarlingdata.com/copying-rowstore-tables/)

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you have an `ID` column in your table `dbo.SourceTable` which is `CLUSTERED` I would suggest making use of that instead of `ROW_NUMBER`. Then, in each batch, increase the value of the range on by the batch size. This will mean that each batch could be different size (if you have gaps in your identity), however, the predicate on your clustered primary key will enable the data engine to *seek* to the rows it needs.

If we assume you want to `INSERT` (up to) 1 million rows at a time, then something like this might be what you want:

```sql
DECLARE @ID bigint = 1,
        @BatchSize bigint  = 1000000;

WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 BEGIN
    SET @ID = @ID + @BatchSize;

    INSERT INTO dbo.DestinationTable WITH (TABLOCKX)(col1, col2, col3, col4)
    SELECT st.col1,
           st.col2,
           st.col3,
           st.col4
    FROM dbo.SourceTable st
    WHERE st.Id >= @ID - @BatchSize
      AND st.ID < @ID;

END;
```

On a table I have in our test environment with ~13million rows, which has an `CLUSTERED` `PRIMARY KEY` using an `IDENTITY` (with very few gaps) this method took 22641ms (22.6 seconds) for batches of 1 million. The method you use, with `ROW_NUMBER`, took 127001ms (over 2 minutes).